# How to apply groupby function to get previuos month count?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe which looks like below:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3'],
            'sym': ['abc','pqr','xyz','lmn','abc','pqr','xyz','lmn','aaa','bbb'],
        'count': ['10','14','25','20','34','23','43','34','10','20']})

dff = dff[['sym','month','count']]
print dff

  sym month count
0  abc     1    10
1  pqr     1    14
2  xyz     1    25
3  lmn     1    20
4  abc     2    34
5  pqr     2    23
6  xyz     2    43
7  lmn     2    34
8  aaa     3    10
9  bbb     3    20
```

I want to create new column to this dataframe named as "prev_count". For creation of this new column "prev_count" need to follow below rule:

- If the previous month is not available in particular group then "prev_count" value should be 0.
- If the previous month is available in the particular group then previous month count value should be the value of "prev_count".

I tried it with groupby function like below:

```
def f(df):

   print df
   return ""

dff['pre_count'] = dff.groupby('sym').apply(f)
```

But I'm unable to understand how I can keep track count value of previous month. Is their any pandas way to do such manipulation on the data?

**Expected Output:**

```
  sym month count    prev_count
0  abc     1    10   0
1  pqr     1    14   0
2  xyz     1    25   0
3  lmn     1    20   0
4  abc     2    34   10
5  pqr     2    23   14
6  xyz     2    43   25
7  lmn     2    34   20
8  aaa     3    10   0
9  bbb     3    20   0
```

Comment: @JohnGalt- Ok thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the `month` is already sorted. Use `shift()` and `fillna(0)` on `sym` groups

```
In [2878]: dff['prev_count'] = dff.groupby('sym')['count'].shift().fillna(0)

In [2879]: dff
Out[2879]:
   sym month count prev_count
0  abc     1    10          0
1  pqr     1    14          0
2  xyz     1    25          0
3  lmn     1    20          0
4  abc     2    34         10
5  pqr     2    23         14
6  xyz     2    43         25
7  lmn     2    34         20
8  aaa     3    10          0
9  bbb     3    20          0
```

Or, `transform`

```
In [2880]: dff.groupby('sym')['count'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1)).fillna(0)
Out[2880]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4    10
5    14
6    25
7    20
8     0
9     0
Name: count, dtype: object
```

Comment: @JohnGalt- Can you please explain in detail how it is considering date for shift(). I didn't understand properly.